# Share extension show console warnings when its open from Safari

Tags: ios, safari, ios8, ios8-share-extension, today-extension

A simple Share extension (Nothing has changed in that just add new target as Share extension). Here i observed that console shows some warning when i run Share extension target from Safari application.

**Reference images:**

1. Choose run target.

[image]

2. Tap on action button from Safari app.

[image]

**Do we have to pass any items, As console warning suggest?**

Console warning:

```
Unknown activity items supplied: (
    "https://www.google.com/?client=safari&channel=iphone_bm",
    "<WBUPrintPageRenderer: 0x7fed6078cc20>",
    "<UIPrintInfo: 0x7fed607c9220>"
)
```